# Speed up an alternative way to get Facebook Fans without using an app-key or CURL

Tags: php, facebook, curl

I have got Facebook data from graph.facebook.com without using CURL by doing some PHP randomness... :)

It's a bit sideways but I don't know how to use CURL and I also don't need to pass any app keys or anything etc!

```
// Create a function to calculate the number of fans.
function calculatefans($facebookid) {
    $file = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$facebookid;
    // Get data from that specific Facebook page    
    $facebookdata = file_get_contents($file);
    // Reverse data from Facebook Graph so that the "likes" figure is at the front
    $facebookbackwards = strrev($facebookdata);
    // Select only the "likes" figure is in the variable
    $offset = strpos($facebookbackwards, ":");
    // Minus 1 from the offset
    $newoffset = $offset-1;
    $fansbackwards = substr($facebookbackwards, 1, $newoffset);
    // Turn the "likes" figure the right way around
    $fans = strrev($fansbackwards);
    // Change the result from a string to an integer so you can do some maths on the result.
    $fanresult = (int)$fans;
    // Use return not echo because you want to do something with the data later.
        return $fanresult;
}
```

However, this is obviously running very slowly... I was wondering if anyone had any ideas about how I could speed this up?

My website I'm running this on is http://www.ibizavote.com. If you see, the code is working however when I add this into the site the site goes from loading in 4.4secs to 14.4seconds.

I'm sure I can speed this up...
Any ideas?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: You should use the facebook php sdk - this does all the CURL for you.  https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/

Comment: Don't you need to add the app-key to get only your own page's facebook fans? I'm looking to get lots of other pages' fans?

Answer (score 0):

The str reversals, substr, strpos are extremely fast.

The slow part will be the web service request. If you do this with curl, you can send multiple requests simultaneously by following the example here and adapting it for the Facebook apis: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php.

Just a heads up though: why aren't your parsing the Facebook response as JSON data? json_decode is implemented in c and is also fast. The string scraping that you're doing here is going to be susceptible to failure if Facebook's output format changes.

Also, you might want to look into FQL where you can generate more complex reports and return only the subset of data that you're looking for. See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

The other thing you want to do in situations like this is cache the response from Facebook so you don't have to ask them all the fan counts on every request.

Parallel requests ( curl_multi_init) + caching are the way to go.